# How to create a BatchFile that will append a Yesterdays date to it's filename?

Tags: batch-file

I need your help for creating a Batch File that will append Yesterdays date to it's filename, example:

Filename.xls will be change to YYYYMMDD_Filename.xls where YYYYMMDD is yesterdays date. I'm trying to do it but failed, as I need to monitor as well date changes like Leap Year, etc..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"I'm trying to do it but failed"*  Show your code, describe your failure. (otherwise, you are asking us to do your code for you).

Comment: Hi Abelenky, 

Managed to make my script works using the following below,

echo wsh.echo date-1 > %temp%\tmp.vbs
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in (
   'cscript.exe //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs'
   ) do (set mm=0%%a& set dd=0%%b& set yr=%%c)
  del %temp%\tmp.vbs


COPY C:\TEST\Champ54321.xls C:\TEST2\%yr%%mm:~-2%%dd:~-2%_Champ12345.xls /Y

Comment: Edit your question. Do not put your code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way to subtract a date.  It uses a neat little trick with xcopy to validate the date.  It does work with leap years.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set rand=%random%
md "dummy%rand%\empty%rand%"

REM Get today's date
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%

REM set the number of days to substract
SET DAYS=1
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%days%) DO CALL :loop

set subdate=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%
echo Yesterday's date is: %subdate%

rd /s /q "dummy%rand%"
pause
endlocal
GOTO :EOF

:loop
  set /a d-=1

  if %d% lss 101 (
    set d=131
    set /a m-=1

    if %m% lss 101 (
      set m=112
      set /a y-=1
    )
  )

xcopy /d:%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%-%y% /t "dummy%rand%\empty%rand%" "dummy%rand%" >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an esoteric and cryptic date subtract method programmed in 3 lines, just to practice `set /A` arithmetic expressions and substring replacements: **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "DPM=31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31"

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get LocalDateTime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM Below code for test the date subtract method
SET /P "DAYS=Days to subtract (one month max): "

:next
set /P "dt=DT: "
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

echo Today: %dt:~0,4%/%dt:~4,2%/%dt:~6,2%

set /A "y=%dt:~0,4%, m=1%dt:~4,2%-100, d=1%dt:~6,2%-100-DAYS"
if %d% lss 1 set /A "y-=!(m-=1),n=m+=12*!m,d+=!(n-=1)*%DPM: =+!(n-=1)*%+!(y%%4)*!(m-2)"
set /A "m+=100, d+=100"

echo Yesterday's date is: %y%/%m:~1%/%d:~1%

goto next
```

This method correctly manage leap years every 4 years but not the cancellation every 400 years, although is very simple add such a feature...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work

echo wsh.echo date-1 > %temp%\tmp.vbs for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ( 'cscript.exe //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs' ) do (set mm=0%%a& set dd=0%%b& set yr=%%c) del %temp%\tmp.vbs COPY C:\TEST\Champ54321.xls C:\TEST2\%yr%%mm:~-2%%dd:~-2%_Champ12345.xls /Y

Thanks!